# How to get global time(not the pc time) using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was creating a countdown timer using javascript; I can use jQuery. I want the global time not the PC time.

How could I get the global time using javascript or the jQuery?

Comment: What do you mean by "global time"? Time relative to GMT, UTC, Martian Standard Time?

Comment: @jam and comment upvoters - *Really?*  UTC and GMT are functionally equivalent.  What else could possibly be meant by "global time, not PC time"?  That's pretty unambiguous to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a time API like:  http://www.timeapi.org/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function myCallback(json) {
          alert(new Date(json.dateString));
     }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://timeapi.org/utc/now.json?callback=myCallback"></script>
```

You can use the UTC methods from `Date` object: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

```
var utcDate = new Date(json.dateString);
alert(utcDate.getUTCFullYear() + '-' + utcDate.getUTCMonth() + utcDAte.getUTCDate());
```

Comment: Sorry. This was an example on how to get the info. Updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hkaKG/1/ and my answer on how to get the UTC time.

Comment: So... My answer is a bad one because I linked to w3schools? Think with your own head boy. ;)

Comment: Great, but an HTTPS version would be even cooler. Currently, my Facebook app can't access it because of the insecure connection.

Comment: @TamásBolvári A quick search in google and found this: https://www.programmableweb.com/category/time/api

Comment: timeapi is not supported anymore

Answer (score 1):

Well unless you make a request to some service that publishes like the current time of an atomic clock or something, you'll have to rely on your computers local time. As JS inherently relies on your local system.

Answer (score 1):

The `Date` object has built-in methods for getting UTC values.  Instead of `myDate.getHours()` use `myDate.getUTCHours()`, etc.

See the MDN reference for JavaScript [date methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Methods_2).

Comment: This still relly on the machine settings, not the real UTC time.

Comment: @rcdmk - ya, I guess it depends on how you read his question.  I read it as a question about local vs universal time.  I didn't see any hint that the question was about handling systems with incorrect date and time settings.

Answer (score 0):

Using your current API with server time like following:

```js
res.send(new Date());
```

You can get an approximate clock difference time with following:

```js
// Get current local time before request
const initialLocalTime = new Date().getTime();

// Request server time
const response = await fetch('/api/time');
const data = await response.json();
const serverTime = new Date(data);

// Get current local time after request
const finalLocalTime = new Date().getTime();

// Calculate the request time
const dateDiff = finalLocalTime - initialLocalTime;

// Apply the request time to server time
serverTime.setTime(serverTime.getTime() + dateDiff);

// Calculate the time difference
const diff = serverTime.getTime() - finalLocalTime;

// Return the final difference time
return diff;
```

And, you can use the `diff` value in your page:

```js
const now = new Date()
now.setTime(now.getTime() + diff);
console.info('Current time:', now);
```