# Get actual date and time with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, date

I'm developing a website where registrations for a particular event will open on a certain date (say, `January 1, 2019`) and will close on another date (say, `January 10, 2019`). I'm using JavaScript to redirect users to the relevant pages if they try to access it on before the 1st or after the 10 of January.

My code so far:

```
var d = new Date();
var startDate = new Date(2019, 0, 1, 8);
var endDate = new Date(2019, 0, 10, 23, 59);

if(endDate-d<0) // Past expiration date
    window.location = "register-closed.html";

else if(startDate-d > 0) // Before starting
    window.location = "register-unavailable.html";
```

The main problem as you might have guessed is that this code takes the local date and time from the user; if I set the date on my device as `2nd January, 2019`, I'm able to access the actual register page, even though it's May right now.

I feel this would be a common problem for many, but I've been unable to find any solution to this. How do I get the **REAL** date and time for my country (India) instead of the device time?

## TL;DR

How do I get the actual date and time for a country (in my case, INDIA) using JavaScript? If I can't use vanilla JS, is there some other method to do so?

**PS**: If you have any solutions that can only be bypassed using methods more complicated than changing your device time, I'll readily accept them. This whole website is just for a high school event, so I don't expect any skilled hackers to spend their time on this :)

Comment: You should take a look at [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/). It's a great library for handling Dates, Timezones and more. But to get something like a real date you are forced to get the date from your server or another server.

Comment: @Jan how does that solve his problem? moment.js will also be vulnerable to people changing their local date and time.

Comment: JavaScript in the browser will always depend on the system clock. Use a server side scripting language like php or node.js

Comment: The problem, Robo, is that if it's very very important that you not allow people to access those pages, you CANNOT do it reliably in javascript anyway. Let's say you did have the exact reliable current date and time -- people could still access your javascript, see what URL it's supposed to go to, and change the flow of the application according to whatever they want. You have to control it on the server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get global time(not the pc time) using javascript or jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9862657/how-to-get-global-timenot-the-pc-time-using-javascript-or-jquery)

Comment: @TKoL The website I'm making is for a school event, and I'm in 12th here (probably high school in America), so I don't expect anyone to go through such a difficult process

Comment: @schadenfreude I disagree that it's a duplicate. As TKoL said, client-side checks are inherently problematic. I have an even simpler example of how it could be "broken" - the user disables JS and visits the page, so they won't even get the AJAX request, much less the redirect.

Comment: @RoboMop I'm not totally convinced it is appropriate, but in your case it might be. You should check out the suggested duplicate if you want to do this in the browser. But *at the very least*, it wouldn't look very professional. At least to people more experienced with web technologies.

Comment: @VLAZ The title of the question is "Get actual date and time with Javascript", the body of the question asks how to get the actual date and time with JavaScript, and you're saying the proposed duplicate, which describes how to get the actual date and time with JavaScript, is not a duplicate?

Comment: @HereticMonkey I've tried out the potential duplicate, but I don't understand JSON, so I can't use the accepted answer

Comment: @HereticMonkey I was suggesting it's an XY problem.

Comment: I've tried moment.js, but it either doesn't work for my question, or I'm just unable to figure it out. Any other answers?

Comment: There is no way of getting the correct date and time in the browser if someone has changed their machine's date and time, without relying on an external server. The accepted answer on the proposed duplicate shows (without having to "know JSON") how to use a public service to do so.

Answer (score 1):

This code will get the date (as in the 30th), month, and year. This uses the `new Date();` variable type. It has several uses, and you can get the output in whatever order using something like `new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)`. That would output something like Wed May 22 2019 10:46:32 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time).

```js
var todaysDate = new Date();

var date = todaysDate.getDate();
var month = todaysDate.getMonth(); 
var year = todaysDate.getFullYear();
if(date === 10 || month === 0 || year === 2019){
//January is 0 because counting starts at 0
...
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Answer (score -1):

you should take a look to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44677169/how-to-get-current-date-time-of-other-country-in-client-side-code-in-javascript) as it seems to answer to your problem using only vanilla JS. Hope it helps :)

Comment: The answers in this link are just for getting the time of a place **with respect to** the device locale, which in my case might be changed. The solutions there depend on the device time as well...